# Python - первод из UTF-8 в binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, binary

Столкнулся с проблемой при парсинге DNS-пакета. Нужно определить запрос это или ответ. За это отвечает 1-битовый флаг QR (0 - запрос; 1 - ответ). [Полное описание заголовка.](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_DNSMessageHeaderandQuestionSectionFormat.htm) В моем случае весь 12-байтовый заголовок выглядит примерна так: **b'\xc9\xeb\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'**. Учитывая, что в 3-й байт попадет *Opcode*, *AA*, *TC*, *RD* помимо искомого *QR*, требуется взять только первый бит. Нашел еще [такое](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=string-literal&unicodeinhtml=hex) про UTF-8. Вопрос: как представить 1 байт в виде 8 битов?

```
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F 
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                      ID                       |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|QR|   Opcode  |AA|TC|RD|RA|   Z    |   RCODE   |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    QDCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ANCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    NSCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
|                    ARCOUNT                    |
+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать так:

```
foo = b'\xc9\xeb\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' # исходная строка
bar = format(foo[2], '08b') # 2-й байт
baz = format(foo[0], '08b') # 0-й байт
> bar
'00000001'
> baz
'11001001'
```

Требуемые биты уже можно извлечь из строки по соответствующему индексу.

```
bar[0]
> '0'
```